# Can I install a through-the-wall AC unit in a window?

Tags: air-conditioning

My landlord bought a wall unit and installed it in a window in my bedroom. There is no housing on the back and it will be exposed to rain and snow. Is this ok?

[image]

Comment: Thanks but should I be able to see the copper parts that are inside the unit? Its hanging out of the window and I can see all of the inner parts. There is no covering. it seems to me when the rain hits it there will be an electrical fire.

Comment: Please post a picture. Usually having innards exposed implies that rodents birds water and UV light can get into it, any having possibly hazardous or unhygienic consequences

Comment: I added a picture of the back of the unit that will be exposed to the rain, snow, birds, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pic. I can't make from it what it is we're looking at. Perhaps someone else can provide a relevant answer, and maybe a picture from a bit further away (less cropped) would help.

Comment: That really doesn't look right.  It's not walls vs windows, it looks like there is a cover missing and that cage was home made.  Nvm rain, small animals can get in.  Can you see the make and model, maybe on a data plate on the bottom of the inside part?  Can you get more/better photos and more angles?

Answer (score 4):

My comment about that looking home-made is incorrect.  That is an LG through the wall A/C.
[image]

There is nothing wrong with installing it in a window.  Make sure it's sealed all around at the sides and/or the flange.  That flange might make it difficult to install on some windows as it is meant to interface with a wall and might not mate well with a window frame.  Perhaps it is removeable?  And make sure the water drips to the outside, away from the wall and if not, use shims to tilt the unit a little and re-seal the sides and bottom.

The issue I mentioned in the comment -- small animals can get inside, not to mention leaves and other debris ---  I don't understand how that isn't a problem here, but that is how the unit was designed, it's not one created by the landlord or installer.

Comment: Wow... weird, but a good find. I'd be concerned about rain/snow/critters/bugs getting into the house between the wall flange and the window. At best, the flange would sit against the window sash leaving a gap between the flange and the glass. This gap would need to have some sort of weather tight seal, and that would be difficult at best. Considering the fact that the AC seems to be held to its angle-iron support with zip ties (lower left of pic), I'd guess that the weather proofing wasn't particularly well done.

Comment: Indeed weird "that is how the unit was designed", so responsibility lies with the manufacturer, and as long as the gaps are sealed and the bracing is strong this is fine in the window. Good find!

Answer (score 3):

A window a/c unit usually cannot be installed through a wall because some of the outside air intakes on the sides would be covered by the wall and these must be fully outside, but AFIK a through-the-wall (TTW) unit could be installed in a window. A TTW unit has its outside intakes further back so these intakes are not blocked by the wall.

One problem with window installation of a TTW unit might be that they might not come with the side sealing kits that window units always come with.

Some through the wall units might be sold separately from the casing designed to hold the unit. If your unit is not fully covered by casing, this would improperly expose the unit to the elements, not to mention being unsightly.

Almost certainly your landlord got the innards without the casing designed to hold and protect the unit. I do not think this would present an extra electric shock hazard *right now* but it could lead to degradation of the wiring by exposure to direct sunlight. Rain and snow on the unit would certainly not be good for the fans, motors and other components.

If I had this in my window, I would not be happy, and I would think about asking the landlord to make it right, but I really like being cool and I would worry that the landlord might decide to just remove the unit and let me be hot.

Comment: It may also depend on the length of time the OP is planning on staying in this place. This is unlikely to fail over the next 12-24 months, but the chances of failure will, likely, increase somewhat rapidly after that. If OPs lease is up in 9 months and she's planning on moving, well, it's most likely the next tenants problem.